# Vuex & Typescript で this.$store を参照できない

Tags: javascript, vue.js, typescript

お世話になっております。
現在`Vuex`と`Typescript`を使用してカウンターアプリを作成しています。

## 質問

`Vuex`のストアを`this.$store`で参照することができない。

- `this.$store` → TS2339: Property '$store' does not exist on type
- `this['$store']` → 正常に動作する

`this['$store']`では正常に動作することから、`store`は問題なく実装できていると考えてます。
また、`increment()`実行時の`this`をダンプすると、`$store`を持っていることは確認できてます。

実際のコードは下記の通りです。

```
<template>
  <div class="test">
    <span class="test__highlight">Cout:</span>{{ count }}
    <button @click="decrement">
      -
    </button>
    <button @click="increment">
      +
    </button>
  </div>
</template>

<style lang="scss" scoped></style>

<script lang="ts">
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex';

export default {
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(['count']),
  },
  methods: {
    increment() {
      console.log(this.$store);
      // TS2339: Property '$store' does not exist on type '{ increment(): void; decrement(): void; }'

      // エラーは発生しない
      this['$store'].dispatch('increment');
    },
    decrement() {
      this['$store'].dispatch('decrement');
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

お力添えいただけますと幸いです。
よろしくお願いいたします。